# Why do I keep getting an error message saying Syntax Error: Unexpected string literal 'data-to-insights.ecommerce.all_sessions_raw' at [2:6]

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to type execute the following BigQuery statement on Google Cloud Platform:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_duplicate_rows, * 
FROM `data-to-insights.ecommerce.all_sessions_raw` 
GROUP BY fullVisitorId, channelGrouping, time, country, city, totalTransactionRevenue, transactions, timeOnSite, pageviews, sessionQualityDim, date, visitId, type, productRefundAmount, productQuantity, productPrice, productRevenue, productSKU, v2ProductName, v2ProductCategory, productVariant, currencyCode, itemQuantity, itemRevenue, transactionRevenue, transactionId, pageTitle, searchKeyword, pagePathLevel1, eCommerceAction_type, eCommerceAction_step, eCommerceAction_option HAVING num_duplicate_rows > 1
```

I got the following error message.

```
Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 
'data-to-insights.ecommerce.all_sessions_raw' at [2:6]
```

I am currently trying to use BigQuery on Google Cloud Platform and it fails with the error shown above. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your table appears to be enclosed on backticks already. Are you sure that you're not running an old query to your console?

Answer (score 0):

Your query worked alright:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_duplicate_rows, * 
FROM `data-to-insights.ecommerce.all_sessions_raw` 
GROUP BY fullVisitorId, channelGrouping, time, country, city, totalTransactionRevenue, 
    transactions, timeOnSite, pageviews, sessionQualityDim, date, visitId, type, productRefundAmount, 
    productQuantity, productPrice, productRevenue, productSKU, v2ProductName, v2ProductCategory, productVariant, 
    currencyCode, itemQuantity, itemRevenue, transactionRevenue, transactionId, pageTitle, searchKeyword, 
    pagePathLevel1, eCommerceAction_type, eCommerceAction_step, eCommerceAction_option 
HAVING num_duplicate_rows > 1
```

and returned 615 rows after processing 5.6 GB.